# Capistrano Nginx Rails, After Rake Db:Migrate "Something went wrong"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, nginx, capistrano

I needed to `migrate` my database, so I made the changes to my local system, pushed them to git, then `cap production deploy`. Once on the service I went to the `current` and ran `rake db:migrate`. Now when I visit my site I receive an error `We're sorry, but something went wrong (500)`. There is no other information and my `/opt/nginx/logs/error.log` is completely blank. How do I fix this?

I'm using Postgresql, capistrano, rails 3, nginx

Comment: what is written on your `production.log` file?

Comment: I'm not sure where that is? It's not with `error.log` or `access.log`

Comment: go to your application's current directory, `my_app/current/log/production.log`. run this command `tail -f production.log` then paste the output here.

Comment: @Emu Thanks. Errors on a view and says object and says undefined method 'variable' this variable was added with this migration meaning the table has not been updated on the server

Comment: so the problem is solved then? @Marcus

Comment: @Emu Not really. How do I migrate my database with nginx, rails, capistrano

Answer (score 0):

If you correctly installed ruby, rails, passenger and nginx, then follow my [gist](https://gist.github.com/imtiaz-emu/dcb87fde71a9562037d2). You should go through the files and change the configuration according to your need. Here, you'll find

- Gemfile // required gems for capistrano deployment
- Capfile
- deploy.rb // change the configuration for your server
- production.rb // change the configuration for your server

After fully configured according to the gist, run 
`cap production deploy:check` # it'll tell you what is missing for deploying your application
then, `cap production deploy`

Always check the `production.log` file if you facing any problem.